# reactjs : Diffrence between regular/arrow functions and react functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What difference you see between regular/arrow functions and react functional component

React functional component

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComp(){
   return <span>test</span>
}
```

Regular function

```
function myFun(){
   return null;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's no difference, it's just what it returns. In the case of React, it returns JSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called `props`) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

From a JavaScript perspective, this is nothing but a function, except for a special return. It's JSX and each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`.

Basically, you can replace the JSX in the example above with something like:

```
React.createElement('h1', null, `Hello ${props.name}`);
```

And this is nothing but a JavaScript :)

And then you can render your component:

```
const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

- You call `ReactDOM.render()` with the `<Welcome name="Sara" />` element.
- React calls the Welcome component with `{name: 'Sara'}` as the props.
- Our Welcome component returns a `<h1>Hello, Sara</h1>` element as the result.
- React DOM efficiently updates the DOM to match `<h1>Hello, Sara</h1>` and you get it on the screen.

There is one important requirement for React functional component!

**Always start component names with a capital letter.**

> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but  represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.

This function from your example can be used as a functional component:

```
function MyFun() { // name should start with a capital
   return null;
}
```

React won't display anything because React [does not render if component returns null](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Comment: teeny-tiny correction: `React.createElement('h1', null, \`Hello, ${props.name}\`)`