# Difference between Regular javascript functions and React Functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to react, we can call hooks from React Functions and not from Regular Javascript functions.

But what is the difference between both of them ?

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626151/reactjs-diffrence-between-regular-arrow-functions-and-react-functional-compone) it seems like there is no difference and it is just different way of writing.

Please provide an example to make the difference more clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

React functions ***are*** Javascript functions, with some *special* rules around them.

React functions:

1. Follow React component naming convention, i.e. [they must be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)
2. Take a single `props` object argument
3. Return valid JSX
4. React functions are ***NEVER*** invoked. A reference to them is passed or they are referenced ***as JSX***

and that's about it.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => <div>{props.greeting}</div>;
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent greeting="Hello World!" />
```

and never `MyComponent({ greeting: "Hello World!" });`

This is because the React framework takes this component reference and converts it to a regular old Javascript function and manages calling this function for you. React manages the component lifecycle.

Contrary to the other answer, plain Javascript functions ***can*** return JSX. See [Rendering Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html). You can assign a JSX literal to a variable, or call a Javascript function that returns a JSX literal.

Example:

```
const getGreeting = (name) => <div>Hello, {name}!</div>;

const MyComponent = (props) => <div>{getGreeting(props.name)}</div>;
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent name="Drew" /> // --> <div>Hello, Drew!</div>
```

Similarly, React hooks are also *just* Javascript functions, but again with *special* rules applied to them. You can read about these [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

1. React hooks follow a naming convention of using a `use-` prefix
2. Only call Hooks **at the top level**. Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
3. Only call Hooks **from React function components**. Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.
4. Can be called in custom React hooks

These are just rules decided on by the React team to make working with and using React hooks manageable and work within React component lifecycle and keep your sanity.